# How do I alias a static method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am putting this code into a wrapper class and therefore need all helper methods to be static. Everything is working besides my seconds method. How do I alias :seconds to a static method?

```
  def self.minutes
    (rand(58) + 1).to_s
  end

  def self.hours
    (rand(22) + 1).to_s
  end

  alias :seconds :minutes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static methods are really instance methods of class's eigenclass, so you can do:

```
class << self
  def minutes
    (rand(58) + 1).to_s
  end

  def hours
    (rand(22) + 1).to_s
  end

  alias :seconds :minutes
end
```

Comment: Okay, I just looked this up and read an article on this. I get classes are objects with their own inheritance chain and namespace. But what does class << self do? Do I put this code inside my current class definition?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 yes, you put this inside body of the class you want to extend with these methods. This construction opens body of the eigenclass of current `self`.